# PDO bindParam with multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, pdo

I'm working on a function to do make PDO updates for arrays in the form: insert_arrays_values=>([0]=>(field_name=>value, field_name2=>$value2),[1]=>(field_name=>value, field_name2=>$value2))

I'm doing this to make batch inserts (as well as updates in another function) to my tables.

```
function sqlinsert($table, $insert_values_arrays){
        $query = "INSERT INTO $table(";
        foreach($insert_values_arrays[0] as $key => $val){
            $query .= $key.',';
        }
        $query = rtrim($query, ',');
        $query .= ") VALUES(";
        foreach$insert_values_arrays[0] as $key => $val){
            $query .= ':'.$key.','
        }
        $query = rtrim($query, ',');
        $query .= " )";
        $stm = $db->prepare($query);
        foreach ($values_array as $column => &$value){
            $stm->bindParam(':'.$column, $value);
        }
        foreach($insert_values_arrays as $values_array){
            $stm->execute();
        }           
}
```

My question is, when I execute() in the foreach of the insert_values_arrays[0], etc, will I need to reference the '$value' directly in the bindParam, or will the foreach loop be executed with the $values_array as I have it to set the values for the unique execute operations?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did this in a simpler way by avoiding bind parameter and just passing the arrays directly to the execute(), like this:

```
function sqlinsert($table, $insert_values_arrays){
    $db = initializePDO();
    $query = "INSERT INTO $table(";
    foreach($insert_values_arrays[0] as $key => $val){
        $query .= $key.',';
    }
    $query = rtrim($query, ',');
    $query .= ") VALUES(";
    foreach($insert_values_arrays[0] as $key => $val){
        $query .= ':'.$key.',';
    }
    $query = rtrim($query, ',');
    $query .= ")";
    $stm = $db->prepare($query);
    foreach($insert_values_arrays as $values_array){
        $stm->execute($values_array);
    }
//working           
}
```

Are there any security implications to avoiding bindParam in this way?